# Quake 3 vstr Rotation with Custom Bots

Tags: quake-3

I am using the following config to cycle through maps on a CTF server:

```
set d1 "devmap q3ctf4 ; set nextmap vstr d2"
set d2 "devmap q3ctf1 ; set nextmap vstr d3"
set d3 "devmap q3ctf2 ; set nextmap vstr d4"
set d4 "devmap q3ctf3 ; set nextmap vstr d5"
set d5 "devmap q3ctf5 ; set nextmap vstr d1"
vstr d1
```

Following this in my config file, I am running a series of addbot commands:

```
addbot uriel 2 blue 100 Uriel
addbot Bobafett blue 2 100 BobaFett
addbot shockwave blue 2 100 Shockwave
addbot wolverine blue 2 100 Wolverine
addbot grinch 2 red 100 TheGrinch

addbot anarki 2 red 100 Anarki
addbot vader 2 red 100 DarthVader
addbot jazz 2 red 100 Jazz
addbot JOKER 2 blue 100 TheJoker
```

The problem is that after the first map, the bots don't re-join automatically.  How can I combine vstr rotation with custom bots?

Additionally (and related), I am using a countdown timer:

```
g_doWarmup 15
```

The same issue happens here...once the game starts the bots are gone and I have to re-add them again.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @agent86 - new question you might know something about :)

Comment: I don't know if its possible to add bots to specific teams via the config, sorry.

Comment: I think yx has done what can be done... you might be out of luck here.  I also looked into [arena files](http://www.wemakemaps.com/arena.htm) but these seem more oriented towards single-player play.  The level of customization available when adding bots to a multiplayer match isn't all that deep.  I also couldn't find any mods that do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to edit your [server config file](http://www.3dgw.com/guides/q3a/index.php3?page=configs.htm) to automatically add bots to fill up empty slots:

> bot_minplayers [number] - Sets the number of minimum slots that will be filled by bots.

If you do not have enough players to exceed that minimum per team, it'll fill the rest of the slots up with bots.

To specify particular bots or add custom bots for your server, you'll have to [modify your bots.txt file](http://planetquake.gamespy.com/View.php?view=Guides.Detail&id=59&game=4)

Comment: Can I specify which bots will be used by bot_minplayers?

Comment: I updated my question to give more detail about my setup.